# Confusing naming in MANE GFF file

Tags: sequence-annotation, gff3, refseq, mane

I'm working with [the MANE v1.2 annotation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/MANE/) (with RefSeq keys) and am puzzled about the ID naming convention being used. Specifically, there are several transcripts (18 by my count) that have hyphenated numbers attached to their IDs, which are otherwise just RefSeq IDs. For example, the entry **NM_000937.5** (for POLR2A) is listed as `"NM_000937.5"` in FASTA, but as `"NM_000937.5-2"` in the GFF. In fact, everywhere in the GFF any reference to POLR2A is listed as `"POLR2A-2"`. This perhaps could make sense if there were multiple transcripts included for the gene, but it is not the case - there are no plain `"POLR2A"` entries nor any `"POLR2A-1"` entries.

What is going on here? Why do these entries have additional numbers attached?

---

For reference, the 18 transcripts with hyphenated names are:

```
MANE ID                 RefSeq ID
rna-NM_001405666.3-2    NM_001405666.3
rna-NM_001291281.3-2    NM_001291281.3
rna-NM_001137667.2-2    NM_001137667.2
rna-NM_017680.6-2       NM_017680.6
rna-NM_002457.5-2       NM_002457.5
rna-NM_001164277.2-2    NM_001164277.2
rna-NM_178167.5-2       NM_178167.5
rna-NM_000937.5-2       NM_000937.5
rna-NM_001324073.3-2    NM_001324073.3
rna-NM_001097639.3-2    NM_001097639.3
rna-NM_152503.8-2       NM_152503.8
rna-NM_001372044.2-2    NM_001372044.2
rna-NM_001417890.1-2    NM_001417890.1
rna-NM_022555.4-2       NM_022555.4
rna-NM_021983.5-2       NM_021983.5
rna-NM_014513.3-3       NM_014513.3
rna-NM_020535.3-5       NM_020535.3
rna-NM_014512.1-9       NM_014512.1
```